# Increase Accuracy on 2D CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been trying to train a 2D CNN for an image classification problem. My data consists of 64 by 64 pixel images each labeled with a number from 1-37. I have my CNN architecture below:

```
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/temp-frames/frames/train', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=256, class_mode='categorical')
validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('/kaggle/input/temp-frames/frames/validation', target_size=(64,64), batch_size=256, class_mode='categorical')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters= 64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation ='relu',strides = (2,2), padding = 'valid', input_shape= (64,64,3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))

model.add(Dense(37)) 
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32, validation_data = validation_dataset, shuffle = True)
```

For some reason, my 2D CNN(get accuracy of 16%) performs worse than my 1D CNN(gets accuracy of 30%). I am wondering if there is any way to improve my model to achieve better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start I would recommend using stride 1, not two in your first layer. In the first two layers (conv2d and maxpool) you are already downsampling the image to 16x16, and the network hasn't had a chance to do much. You want to have at least a few layers for each unique number of filters before you downsample.

E.g architecture that might work better:

(conv2d 64 filters, stride 1) x 3

conv2d 128 filters, stride 2

(conv2d 128 filters, stride 1) x 3

conv2d 256 filters, stride 2

(conv2d 256 filters, stride 1) x 3

flatten

dense layers

For more ideas for architecture design, I recommend looking at models such as VGG:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf (page 3).

You won't be able to verbatim copy those since your data is smaller, but note how they have more convolutional layers and less dense layers. They also don't downsample as harshly in the beginning.

I'm also curious as to the size of your dataset, and what is your training/validation/testing split. Do you successfully get close to 100% accuracy on the training data?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. My dataset has a size of around 10000 images and I split it 70% training, 15% val, 15% testing. I can get to 100% acc with enough epochs.

Comment: Sounds good; yeah in that case it's probably an architecture issue. Note I fixed a typo in the strides in my example; x3 layers should have stride 1.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test the architecture out right now.

Comment: Should I add MaxPooling(2,2) after each Conv2d layer?

Comment: Nope. Maxpool is for downsampling; 64x64 -> 32x32. A CNN layer with stride two does the same thing and more; 64x64 goes to 32x32. So in many modern architectures, maxpool isn't used anymore. Hence the two layers I include that have stride 2.

Comment: Thanks again! If I decide to get a new dataset with 256 by 256 images, would the architecture still work? Or would I have to change the kernel size or batch sizes or other hyperparams

Comment: As a disclaimer, I haven't tried the above architecture; I would recommend seeing what other people have done with similar image sizes. You would have to change number of downsamplings or filter sizes, so that the flattened output matches the dense input.

Comment: Thank you! I will experiment around with the filter sizes.